# Merge two PNG images with PHP. Output image CHANGES and wrong opacity

Tags: php, image, gd

I need to merge the following images, however my solution is not working.

My code is the following (I pass the URL of the images to the script via GET parameter)

```
<?php
$dest = imagecreatefrompng($_GET['img1']);
$src = imagecreatefrompng($_GET['img2']);

imagecopymerge($dest, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1500, 1500, 50);

$white = imagecolorallocate($dest, 255, 255, 255);
imagecolortransparent($dest, $white);

header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($dest);
?>
```

Both image are PNG with transparent background and both are 1500x1500.

First image:

[image]

Second image:

[image]

What I get:
[image]

Why can't I make the final image have the right opacity? I tried changing the last value of `imagecopymerge()` to 0 or 100 but in those cases I only get one image or another. I need them both, exactly overlapped on one another!

Also, if you look carefully around the gem in the final image, there is some extra blue color... how is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by setting the resulting image to use image transparency rather than per-pixel alpha-channel transparency by your call to `imagecolortransparent` which sets any white (`#ffffff`) pixels to 100% transparent.

The artefacts ('extra blue colour' and edge pixels) on the resulting image are caused by the alpha-channel transparency from the original images not being saved and the pixels (which were 100% transparent but not white) showing their original colour.

The 'washed out' look of your result comes from telling `imagecopymerge` to merge the two images with 50% transparency.

The solution is to use the correct alpha settings:

```
<?php

$dest = imagecreatefrompng($_GET['img1']);
$src = imagecreatefrompng($_GET['img2']);

imagesavealpha($dest, true);

imagecopy($dest, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1500, 1500);

header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($dest);
```